# how can i display the result of two tables in gridview display yii

Tags: php, yii

I have two tables Table A and Table B.

I have the pk of table A ,as fk called member_id in table B.

While girdview display of table B, I want to show the "Member name" in table A, using the "member_id" in table B.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'transaction-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'member_id',
    'Location',
    ...
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup a relation to that table, and you can use the relation to reference that field like this:

```
$data->member->name;
```

In your transaction model you would place something like:

```
public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'member' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Member', 'member_id'),// foreign key
        );
    }
```

and for grid you would do like:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'transaction-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
       array(
            'header' => 'Member',
            'name' => 'member_id',
            'value' => '$data->member->name'
        ),

    'Location',
    ...
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
));
```

Comment: Hi, I have done above steps but, I'm getting error as `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ` . file and line number is `/var/www/Yii/yii-1.1.13.e9e4a0/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php(784)`